# Representation of roots of unity.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

How to represent solutions of $\sqrt[26]{1}$ with solutions of $\sqrt[26]{-1}$?

I know that $$w_{k}=\cos\left(\frac{0+2k\pi}{26}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{0+2k\pi}{26}\right), \; \; k=\overline{0,25}$$
and $$z_{k}=\cos\left(\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{26}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{26}\right), \; \; k=\overline{0,25}$$
But I cannot establish connection that would rewrite $\sqrt[26]{1}$ using $\sqrt[26]{-1}$ i.e. $w_k$ using $z_k$.

Comment: But, but,,....you just *did*.... $\sqrt[26]{1} = w_k$ and $\sqrt[26]{-1} = z_k$.

Comment: Hmm... Did I really? I imagined it to be in the form $w_k=f(x) z_k$ i.e. $\sqrt[26]{1}=f(x)\sqrt[26]{-1}$ where then again $f(x)$ is something that makes sense in the context... if you understand me properly.

Comment: I did not understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $1=e^{i(2k\pi)}$ and $-1=e^{i(2k+1)\pi}$

Thus

$$w_k=\sqrt[26]{1}=e^{\frac{i(2k\pi)}{26}}=e^{\frac{i((2k+1-1)\pi)}{26}}=e^{\frac{i[(2k+1\pi)]-i\pi}{26}}=z_ke^{\frac{-i\pi}{26}}=z_k\sqrt[26]{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

You yourself have already written the relation inadvertently. Here it is in a clearer form:
$$\sqrt[26]{-1}=\sqrt[26]{1} e^{i\pi/13}$$